# Python as virtual drive

Tags: python, filesystems, virtualbox, iso

I have a python script that has the following functions:

```
save (File, Path, Filename)

get (Path, Filename) #returns File

rename (Path, Filename, NewFilename)

drag (Path, Filename, NewPath)

overwrite (File, Path, Filename)

getObjectsInPath (Path) #returns String with file and folder names in specific Path

delete (Object)
```

I can store as much as I like in it. There are only very slow Storage accesses ...

Now I want to turn it into a virtual hard drive and connect it virtually to my system. Is that possible? If not, maybe as a network drive?

Just like ISO files are virtually connected as storagedevices ...

What i have tried yet:

Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find a library in Python that supports this.

I work with Raspberry Pi OS (32bit) on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I would also be able to switch to a Manjaro Linux (64 bit) on a "normal PC". This is in the same network with the Pi.

I am very sure that there is a solution, even if it is not very easy.

Warm greetings

Boka

Comment: So your "virtual storage" is on Rasberry Pi and you want to access to it from same network? Why do you need python for that? There're plenty of ways to share access.

Comment: no, its not a storage on an raspberry pi, the files are stored online by a script and can be acessed with the commands above

Comment: _Now I want to turn it into a virtual hard drive_, means in other words: Instead of `rm somefile.txt` you want to run `delete('somefile.txt')` that was defined in your Python script ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible on Linux and MacOS.

There *is* a solution using FUSE in these environments, which is a OS level feature and supported by many programming languages. It can be integrated with Python in many ways, a simple one could be [fusepy](https://pypi.org/project/fusepy/).

There's some example [janten/dpt-rp1-py](https://github.com/janten/dpt-rp1-py/blob/master/dptrp1/cli/dptmount.py), preparing a http API like file protocol for linux to be mounted.